# The fulltext filter daemon host (FDHost) process stops abnormally on SQL Alwayson Cluster

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2017, full-text-search

We added a new SQL Always-On Cluster (FCI) 2017 and some of the databases needed  full text filter service. So we also added that feature to the install. Ever since we did that we have been getting the error that it stopped abnormally every minute filling up our error log. Here is the full error message.

> The fulltext filter daemon host (FDHost) process has stopped abnormally. This can occur if an incorrectly configured or malfunctioning linguistic component, such as a wordbreaker, stemmer or filter has caused an irrecoverable error during full-text indexing or query processing. The process will be restarted automatically.

Is there any recommendations to avoid this or any best practices with regard to Full text service running on alwayson clusters?

Answer (score 1):

First, verify the service account, whether it has appropriate permissions on the server.

Then  consider Re-configuring [Word Breakers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-word-breakers-and-stemmers-for-search?view=sql-server-2017) as previous version of Word Breakers might not compatible with SQL 2017. [For more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/upgrade-full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017#FT_Upgrade_Options)

Comment: The service account has appropriate permissions. The error is still filling up the error log. and reconfiguring of word breakers doesn't seem to be related. Anyone else?